# how to return something from a Ninject Interceptor

Tags: ninject, interceptor

I have written a common validator as part of Ninject interceptor. My requirement is that I have to return a response object, just like how any service method in my project returns, for consistency sake. By returning a response object also helps me to send back an appropriate validation message when the validator fails. How do I do that in the interceptor? I understood that the Intercept() returns nothing. I tried throwing an exception but I don't know where to catch it. Can someone help me?

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var validationFails = false;

        if (validationFails)
        {
            // return an object
            // response.ErrorMessage = "Validation Error"

            // Or throw exception, but where should I catch it
            throw new Exception(statusMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to hook up my interceptor to business layer methods, instead of service methods, and am able to return proper return value as part of my response.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the ReturnValue and don't call Proceed when validation fails.

```
public class MyRequestHandler
{
   Response ProcessRequest(string input) { return new Response(); }
}

public MyValidationInterceptor : IInterceptor 
{
    public void Intercept( IInvocation invocation )
    {
        if (NeedsValidation(invocation.Method) && 
            !IsValidRequest((string)invocation.Arguments[0]))
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue =
                              new Response { ErrorMessage = "Validation Error" };
            return;
        }

        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that too. But for some reason, my service call always shows it as a '400 Bad Request', and didn't return anything back.

Comment: So I'm making a service call, hitting MyServiceMethod(), which intern calls a business method and goes on.. I have an interceptor registerd to the Service project and gets triggered before initiating the service call. So when the interceptor returns an object, it's always a '400 Bad Request'. My cursor haven't yet hit the service method.

But when I've tried registering the interceptor with the business project, and I'm able to return whatever I've set in the interceptor. The only difference is, I've hit the service method now, went into interceptor, and was able to return something.

Comment: Public object MyServiceMethod(int param)
{
 return BusinessLayer.MyBusinessMethod(int param);
}

This seem strange to me. Why I was unable to return something, before hitting the service method, but able to return, after I entered into the method. To return soemthing, does it have to be in some method? Does that make any sense? Am I missing something here?